# How to see if this functions are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

> Is this set linearly independent? $A=\left\{ \arctan(x), \arctan(2x), \arctan\big(\frac{3x}{1-2x^2}\big)\right\}$

I've tried using the Wronskian
$$W(A)= \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\arctan(x) & \arctan(2x) & \arctan\big(\frac{3x}{1-2x^2}\big) \\
\frac{1}{1+x^2} & \frac{2}{1+4x^2} & \frac{6x^2+3}{4x^2+5x^2+1} \\
-\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2} & -\frac{16x}{(4x^2+1)^2} & -\frac{6x(8x^4+8x^2+3)}{(4x^2+5x^2+1)^2} \end{array} \right|,$$

but expanding the determinant gives an extensive term difficult to simplify. So, does there exist an easier method to see whether the set is linearly independent?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

$$\arctan\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b}=a+b.$$

Comment: There's a good chance I'm missing something, but I'm struggling to see how to constructively apply this identity to the given set of functions.

Comment: @K.Power Next hint: $1+2=3,1\cdot2=2$ (not kidding).

Comment: I knew I had to use that fact, but I wasn't sure how to bring it into play because $\arctan$ isn't linear. However, I realised I was thinking about it all wrong. If you just remember that $\arctan$ is surjective you can use your hints far more productively. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Power: indeed, $\arctan$ isn't linear, but... $a+b$ is :-)

Comment: When I say $\arctan$ is surjective, I really mean that $\tan$ is surjective obviously :/